# # sign in CSS selectors

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Some CSS selectors have `#` in front of them, what does that mean?

Comment: do programmers even use google anymore, or is StackOverflow.com their homepage? =)

Comment: Admittedly the `#` character is one of the harder things to google for.  :-)

Comment: Yes I don't know how to escape it.

Comment: @RPM1984 it actually bags the question do programmer even read anymore?
Any basic CSS tutorial will begin with this

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's the ID selector, a fundamental feature of the CSS standard. It matches the HTML element with the given ID, according to the `id` attribute (assuming a conforming document, of course). See [the W3C Selectors spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#id-selectors) for more.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <style type="text/css">
  #my-div {
      color: #f00;
  }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="my-div">This text will be red.</div>
  <div id="another-div">This text will not be red.</div>
</body>

</html>
```

You may also have seen the `#` notation used in a URL fragment identifier to refer to named anchors (`<a name="some-anchor"></a>`). These can also point to elements with certain IDs in your page, just like named anchors, and I gather that it's why CSS uses the same notation for selecting IDs.

Comment: I'll just leave this here. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120025/will-i-be-downvoted-for-giving-a-w3schools-link

Comment: Dont forget the "Element" vs "Class" in CSS. An "Element" `#myElement` should only be used once per page, where a class `.myClass` can be used multiple times.

Answer (score 3):

The selector, `#foo` will match any element with an ID attribute with a value of "foo".

```html
<style type='text/css'>
#foo { color: red; }
</style>

<div id='foo'>red text</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

It selects based on the id of html element...

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#id-selectors

```html
<style>
#myDiv { }
</style>

<div id="myDiv">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

In CSS,

`#` is Mention for ID Selector

`.` is Mention for Class Selector

Answer (score 2):

You might also have seen something like

```
div#myDiv {}
```

Which means "a DIV-tag with ID set to 'myDiv'"